# Trouble using jdbc:outbound-gateway when query returns empty result set

Tags: spring-integration

I have noticed the following unexpected behavior and can reproduce it with the Spring Integration sample basic/jdbc

Run the Spring Integration sample basic/jdbc and immediately attempt to find a name that does not exist
i.e. run using the Spring Integration sample basic/jdbc run Main.java, enter 1 to Find person, enter Mark

A ReplyRequiredException is thrown because no row is found.
If I change the int-jdbc:outbound-gateway definition in spring-integration-context.xml to use requiresReply="false",
then the call to findPersonByName blocks until the int:gateway times out after the configured 5 seconds.

This is a very typical operation where I want to use Spring Integration jdbc:outbound-gateway to return a list of 0 or more items.
It seems to work fine for result sizes 1 or more.
However, neither behavior is desirable when 0 results are found.  I don't want the exception because sometimes this behavior is expected and I also don't want to block until timeout.
In the case of the Exception, I can use try/catch but the framework logs the exception at the WARN level and I don't want to handle expected behavior, 0 items returned, with exception handling, try/catch.
Is there a way to configure the flow in Spring Integration sample basic/jdbc to return without blocking or throwing an Exception when the name is not found, i.e. just return an empty list?

Answer (score 2):

A number of users have asked for this and we will look into it.

In the meantime, there are a couple of work-arounds.

1. Add an `error-channel` to some upstream component (e.g. `<gateway/>`) to handle the exception.
2. Add an [ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) to the JDBC gateway's `request-handler-advice-chain`. Set it's `returnFailureExpressionResult` property to true, which causes the result of the `onFailureExpression` to be returned to the calling thread instead of throwing the exception.

Comment: russel: I am trying to add error-channel attribute to 'int-jdbc:outbound-gateway' but it says that error-channel is not allowed to appear on this element.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers; especially when it's 4 years old. Ask a new question instead. As I said in this answer, error channels are defined on **inbound** endpoints, not outbound; or you can add an [expression evaluating advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to outbound endpoints.

Comment: Thanks @gary russel for the answer. I will take care next time to post a new question instead of adding a question as a comment.

Comment: Just runnning into this one myself.  Anything new on this subject since 7 years ago?

Comment: I've tried the ```si-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain``` approach, setting ```returnFailureExpressionResult``` to ```true``` and setting the ```onFailureExpression``` to an empty array, but this either throws an exception (if ```requires-reply``` is true) or never returns (if ```requires-reply``` is false).

Comment: Doesn't look like it has changed, but the advice should work so it's probably mis-configured; I suggest you ask a new question, referencing this one and show your configuration, stack trace etc.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to use a `service activator` with a `jdbcTemplate` instead. This way, you control the response yourself.

Obviously this is not an ideal approach, but it is arguably cleaner than resorting to the use of error-channels or handler advice for what feels like it should be a normal response scenario. One potential downside (though I haven't explored this in depth yet) is you may lose some additional out-of-the-box instrumentation provided by the framework for the jdbc gateway (say additional `JMX` properties/method exposure, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I need to use outbound gateway only, the above option is not available.