# spring-integration jdbc outbound-gateway advice for handling empty result-sets

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-integration, declarative

I'm taking @gary-russel's suggestion and opening a new question w.r.t this older question ( [Trouble using jdbc:outbound-gateway when query returns empty result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319614/trouble-using-jdbcoutbound-gateway-when-query-returns-empty-result-set) ) about spring-integration JDBC outbound-gateway calls on requests that return an empty result-set.

I've tried to use handler advice to get the request to return an empty array rather than throwing an exception.

Could you advise why this advice is not right?

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi      = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

             xmlns:beans    = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:jdbc     = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

             xmlns:int      = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:int-jdbc = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"

             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans            https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc             https://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration      https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd">

    <int:gateway id="getAllCustomers-Gateway"
                 default-request-channel="getAllCustomers"
                 service-interface="demo.StringInputJsonOutputGatewayMethod" />

    <int:channel id="getAllCustomers" />

    <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway id="getAllCustomers-OutboundGateway"
                               request-channel="getAllCustomers"
                               query="select * from Customer"
                               data-source="dataSource"
                               max-rows="0" >
        <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice" >
                <beans:property name="onSuccessExpressionString"     value="payload ?: {} " />
                <beans:property name="returnFailureExpressionResult" value="#{true}"        />
                <beans:property name="onFailureExpressionString"     value="{}"             />
            </beans:bean>
        </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource" >
        <beans:property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"         value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" />
        <beans:property name="username"    value="sa" />
        <beans:property name="password"    value=""   />
    </beans:bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" >
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:/schema.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans:beans>
```

The test database is initialized with this script (`schema.sql`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    ID         BIGINT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

The outbound-gateway is throwing an exception:

```
org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'getAllCustomers-OutboundGateway', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.
```

Any suggestions or pointers appreciated.

**Some debugging followup:**

I can see that the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is called to evaluate the `successExpression` but that this does not alter return result, even when a success expression is provided, something like `payload ?: {}`.  The `failureExpression` is not consulted because the `null` result failure exception from the `JdbcOutboundGateway` is thrown after AdviceChain is run.

The most surprising part of this `JdbcOutboundGateway` problem is that the method `handleRequestMessage()` does receive an empty list from the JDBC call, which seems perfectly valid, but it then goes on to explicitly set this to `null`.

```java
        if (this.poller != null) {
            ...
            list = this.poller.doPoll(sqlQueryParameterSource);
        }
        Object payload = list;
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @artem-bilan's suggestions.  This seems to do the trick in the end.

Add a custom advice handler extension to `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```java
package demo;

import org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList;

public class ReplaceNullWithEmptyListHandlerAdvice extends ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice {

    private static final List<Object> EMPTY_LIST = unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>());

    @Override
    protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
        final Object result = super.doInvoke(callback, target, message);
        return result != null ? result : EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}
```

Now can set the advicechain like this:

```xml
    <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway id="getAllCustomers-OutboundGateway"
                               request-channel="getAllCustomers"
                               query="select * from Customer"
                               data-source="dataSource"
                               max-rows="0" >
        <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <beans:bean class="demo.ReplaceNullWithEmptyListHandlerAdvice" />
        </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your point is to return an empty list as is, not `null` as it is there by default in the `JdbcOutboundGateway`.

The `null` is valid a result from the `Joinpoint` execution in the AOP Advice.
The logic in that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is like this:

```
    try {
        Object result = callback.execute();
        if (this.onSuccessExpression != null) {
            evaluateSuccessExpression(message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Since `null` is OK return, yo just go to the `evaluateSuccessExpression()` without expecting its result at all. So, in the end we just return that `null`.

This null is consulted in the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`:

```
    if (result != null) {
        sendOutputs(result, message);
    }
    else if (this.requiresReply && !isAsync()) {
        throw new ReplyRequiredException(message, "No reply produced by handler '" +
                getComponentName() + "', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.");
    }
```

You may really consider to set that `requiresReply` to `false` to ignore empty lists from query execution. We may revise our "empty list" logic though, but for now it is converted directly to `null`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3333.

You may consider to implement a a custom `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` and check for the `callback.execute()` result and return an empty list as you might expect.

It is also possible with the mentioned `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, but it is a bit involved with other options and exceptions throwing from the `onSuccessExpression`.

Comment: Setting ```requires-reply="false"``` on the ```JdbcOutboundGateway``` leads to a wait for a timeout which is clearly not an improvement.

Comment: No, that's not its goal. It is really an interceptor to do something else when the result is OK.

Comment: My misunderstanding was in thinking that ```ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice``` could return a modified result based upon the JDBC returned result.  But it seems that it is not considering the polled result, but only the original input message.  I will try a custom AdviceHandler.  thanks for the help.